# How to find repetitive record, not using aggregate functions and group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

There are singers and songs tables in db, we have to find who have most songs numbers by not using aggregate functions and group by keyword.

[tables in turkish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLFOI.jpg)

Table is translated

```
song(sarkino, name, tour, duration, composerno, author no)
singer(singer, name, type, birthDate, birthPlace)
album(albumno, name, year, price, singer, stock quantity)
Song in the album(albumno, song, order)
composer(composcino, name, tour)
author(author, name)
```

Question original:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Aun.jpg)

Question is translated:

> Solve the author numbers of the authors who wrote the most lyrics, as
> we did in the classroom (in the example in the presentation) without
> using the aggregate function or group by.

Comment: This is my HW the instructor wanted to solve this way otherwise i can use these functions to solve easy

Comment: I can't think of a way to solve without `group by` . And it is pointless doing so

Comment: You could do it using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `LIMIT`, but why you would want to is beyond me. I'd suggest asking your instructor for help rather than SO in this case. In fact, I'd recommend it in pretty much every case where you are unsure on homework - they are paid to teach you, let them earn their money!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: provide sample data and desired output

Comment: MySQL or Postgres? Please don't add DBMS tags that do not apply

Comment: Are you allowed to do the aggregate manually ? If you want to find how many songs somene have to somehow count them and find who has the largest(max) number of songs, and those are aggregated functions. Buf if you do it manually, you could just get all the records and count them yourself by hand. (Which is a rather pointless task when you have a database, but it might satisfy your homework)

Comment: i am searching all possible way but i did not find , i dont think to solve this problem without group by and order by but the instructor defend that there is a way to solve this problem without this functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ergest mentioned, the very standard approach is to use `GROUP BY` with `COUNT`. But well, today your teacher likes challenge.

#### Alternative Solution from [GarethD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048425/garethd) (which absolutely fits the requirement)

I would like to recap [GarethD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048425/garethd) comment in my answer, the credit is all to him.

> If the instructor considers COUNT(*) an aggregate function even when used in a windowed function, this wouldn't be a viable solution. If the only requirement is to get the singer with the most songs, then an alternative is to use ROW_NUMBER() which is almost certainly not an aggregate function by anyone's definition

```sql
SELECT s.name, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY Songs.id) AS number_of_songs
FROM singers AS s
    JOIN Songs
        ON Songs.singer_id = s.id
ORDER BY number_of_songs DESC  
LIMIT 1
```

| name | number_of_songs |
| --- | --- |
| Linkin Park | 5 |

[DBFiddle of GarethD](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4YkbCs9f587FpoGvdyvUiR/1)

#### My original solution using `COUNT OVER PARTITION BY`

You will need to use an advance version of `COUNT`, by combine with `OVER (PARTITION BY singer_id)` , which have a same effect compare to `COUNT` `GROUP BY singer_id`. This will count all the song records over a specified partition `singer_id`, which mean a total song records of a singer_id.

Since you add a bunch of tags of different SQL db type, I will pick **Postgres** to write a sample demo snippet. Don't worry because the `COUNT(*) OVER PARTITION` syntax is likely to be the same for every SQL database

```sql
WITH singers(id, name) AS (
    VALUES(1, 'Lady Gaga'),
    (2, 'Elton John'),
    (3, 'Linkin Park')
),
songs(id, name, singer_id)
AS (
    VALUES(1, 'Born This Way', 1),
    (2, 'Rocket Man', 2),
    (3, 'Numb', 3),
    (4, 'In The End', 3),
    (5, 'Papercut', 3),
    (6, 'Can You Feel The Love Tonight?', 2),
    (7, 'Tiny Dancer', 2),
    (8, 'Your Song', 2),
    (9, 'Waiting For The End', 3),
    (10, 'Forgotten', 3)
)

SELECT singers.*, song_count.number_of_songs
FROM singers
JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT singer_id, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY singer_id) as number_of_songs
FROM songs) song_count
ON singers.id = song_count.singer_id
ORDER BY song_count.number_of_songs DESC;
```

| id | name | number_of_songs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Linkin Park | 5 |
| 2 | Elton John | 4 |
| 1 | Lady Gaga | 1 |

The `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` clause is used to remove duplicated record of `singer_id` `number_of_songs` select

```sql
SELECT singer_id, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY singer_id) as number_of_songs
FROM songs;
```

| singer_id | number_of_songs |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |

Check out this [db fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4YkbCs9f587FpoGvdyvUiR/0)

*Reference*
[Postgresql Window Function Tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/)

Comment: If the instructor considers `COUNT(*)` an aggregate function even when used in a windowed function, this wouldn't be a viable solution. If the only requirement is to get the singer with the most songs, then an alternative is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` which is almost certainly not an aggregate function by anyone's definition, e.g. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4YkbCs9f587FpoGvdyvUiR/1

Comment: Hmm, yes you're right @GarethD, I like your solution, please put it as a separated answer to this post, and feel free to reuse my db-fiddle :)

Comment: Hi @GarethD, I edited my answer combined with your suggestion (since you haven't created another answer), and put it on top (which I believe better fit the requirement). I will  remove it if you decide to answer separately, the credit is all yours.

Comment: thanks for solutions i will try thank you so much